# Rstudio Writing a dataframe to multiple excel files and sheets

Tags: r, xlsx, xlconnect

I am trying to write a dataframe to multiple files and sheets based on account name and currency. For example 
Account  Ccy
Ab11165 GBP
Ab11179 USD
F244144 AUD
Ab11165 USD

I have tried doing the following which creates the filenames but it is extremely slow in creating them is there a better/faster way of doing this also I don't know how to write the sheets for each currency this is what I currently have.

```
 for(cur in 1:length(ccy)){
    for(an in 1:length(acn)){

    df=sqldf(paste("select * from df where CCY='",ccy[cur],"' and  accounts='",acn[aaa],"'",sep = ""))
       if(length(df[,1])>0){          
    wb <- writeWorksheetToFile (paste(folder,acn[aaa],".xlsx",sep=""), data = df,sheet = ccy[ccc],startRow = 1,startCol=1, header=TRUE)
    }}}
```

Expectation I should have 3 files and the sheetsnames should contain the relevant currency but using XLConnect seems to be really slow in writing the file and is not working correctly with the currenct element.

Comment: The package `openxlsx` may better suits you.

Comment: Thanks I have not used openxlsx before so I will try and see how I get on and update once I have attempted this.

Comment: I have attempted to use openxlsx but I do not have Rtools installed.